# log4j with multiple applications in websphere

Tags: spring, web-applications, log4j, websphere

I have two applications (war) deployed on a single websphere application server. Both applications have their own log4j properties and they are loaded from their respective web.xml as

From web.xml of App1

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>  
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:app1/app1Log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

From web.xml of App2

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>  
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:app2/app2Log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Both applications create separate log files.

The problem I'm facing is When I restart the app server, log file for only one application is created. Log statements for 2nd application dont get written to any file. If I stop and start app2 again, then log files for app2 get created and logs are written for both the application.

I verified that the classloader policy at server level is "Multiple" and "parent last". Enabled the class loader service and verified that for both apps log4j.jar is loaded from WEB-INF/lib of corresponding wars. I even tried to set different "start order" for both apps, disabled "parallel start" at server level. But none of the options helped.

Both the log files get written when I start the applications individually after a delay, but one of them dont get written if I start them at the same time. Any help on how to overcome this problem is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
SMan

Comment: Did you try your own servlet context listener to initialize log4j instead of using org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener?

Comment: Thanks fnt, yes initializing the log4j through a custom listener creating both the logs. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: You might want to file a bug - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR
Under the hood Spring uses quite sophisticated techniques for classloading, including the use of context class loaders. This could lead to undesirable effects like the one you observer.